# Inverse relation $0 ≤x − y ≤ 1$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let the relation $R:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ givenas $xRy$ iff $0 ≤x − y ≤ 1$i.e $R=\{(x,y):0 ≤x − y ≤ 1\}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. How do I find an inverse of this relation?

Is it  $R^{-1}=\{(x,y):0 ≤y − x ≤ 1\}$?. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: To find the inverse, you literally switch $x$ and $y$.  Done.  :-)

Comment: Yea that say Wiki hehe but How can I prove it?

Comment: What definition of the inverse relation are you using? I ask because it ought to be an immediate consequence of the definition.

Comment: but then always the inverse relation exists?

Comment: Yes, the inverse relation always exists. As the answer of @zoli shows, every relation has an inverse relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the inverse of $R$, $R^{-1}$, is that for any $x,y$ $xRy$ iff $yR^{-1}x$.

$xRy$ means that $0\leq x-y \leq 1$ that is, $xRy$ iff $x\geq y$ and $0 \leq \mid x-y\mid \leq 1$. To get the inverse we have to require $x \leq y$  and $0 \leq \mid x-y\mid \leq 1$ which is the same as  that requiring $0\leq y-x \leq 1$ as the OP suggested.